# Parse PE header in java

Tags: java

I know how to load a file in memory but in java how can i define a structure to a memory address?

What I am trying to do is parse a PE **(PORTABLE EXECUTABLE)** file header. How can I do that without external libs.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? You can certainly just manipulate your file using a byte array if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want you are trying to read the PE file, but you don't have any machine readable definitions of the file. In Java you can't really have a class that just maps to arbitrary memory, so you will have to just make a bunch of constants with the offsets and sizes of the data in the header. And then you can make some class that will use these constants to return the correct bytes corresponding to what you want.

Comment: I can't think of any, you might try some googling, but you should be able to make something up in the time it will take you to look for the examples. Imaging an array with pairs of offset, length which can be indexed by a constant for the field, and then a simple method to pull the data out. It should not be much work.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://code.google.com/p/jpexe/source/browse/src/com/google/code/jpexe/PEFile.java?spec=svn2a73c57c6e5532365ce12126efa7e902e4c759db&r=c674a40f25833836de99644ff7583e8c9c7d3dc6

I found this source in google project. I haven't tried this out yet. I hope this will be usefull. I you have any better solutions share it here, me too looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try dorkbox PeParser：https://github.com/dorkbox/PeParser

```
PE pe = new PE("C:\\my.exe");
System.out.println(pe.isPE());
System.out.println(pe.getInfo());
```

Comment: It's too bad PeParser only seems to output PE information in text form (via `getInfo()`). It *did* help me figure how to get something particular I needed (certificate offset and length).